# Wordpress with index.html on nginx (debian)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, debian, nginx-config

I have a server with nginx (php-fpm), but I need the index to be index.html.

My configuration is this:

```
server { 
    listen 80 default_server;

    #SSL configuration listen *:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/my.dev.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my-key.pem;    

    root /home/path/to/misite.dev; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm; 
    server_name misite.dev ;

    location / { 
        try_files index.html $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
    }
    location ~ \.php$ { 
        try_files $uri =404;    
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;   
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;    
        include fastcgi.conf; 
    } 
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {     
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;   
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";     
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
    }
    location = /robots.txt { 
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
    }
    location ~ /\. { 
        deny all; 
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
    } 
}
```

By having this, only the index.html works, but nothing with php, and by removing the location's index.html, everything works fine with php, but not the index.html

```
location / {try_files -> index.html <- $ uri / /index.php?$args;}
```

Do you know how I can do it so that both cases work?

(index.html and dynamic pages with php like mysite.com/tag/my-tag)

I hope I have explained well.

Comment: Try putting `try_files` back to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` and changing your `index` directive to `index index.html index.php;`.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `/index.html` as the first parameter to `try_files` will break things.

The `index` directive will look for matching files in the order presented. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

So if you have a directory containing more than one type of index file, simply construct your `index` statement in the order you would like Nginx to prioritise them.

For example:

```
index index.html index.php;
```